# How to increase the size of the zn-badge?

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-zorro-antd, ng-zorro-mobile

When I increase the badge size, the top and bottom numbers are displayed and I am currently unable to insert a spacing between them.

[image: badge]

Could you help me insert this 'spacing' between the numbers displayed inside the circle?

html:

```
<nz-badge class="badge" [nzCount]="44" nzOverflowCount=999>
    <a class="head-example"></a>
</nz-badge>
```

css:

```
.ant-badge-count {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: We need a bit more code. Can you show us your html at least ?

Comment: i edited question with my html code :)